# Smooth Camera Follow with Voxel Based Sphere

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am very new to Unity and just got done yesterday following the Roller Ball example on the learn page here at Unity3d.

To practice what I have learned I wanted to try and recreate something similar using my own art and making the game different. I have been playing around with Voxel Art and I am using MagicaVoxel to create my assests. I created the walls, the ground etc.. and all is well.

Then came the player object, the sphere. I created one as close to a sphere as possible with magicaVoxel and it rolls fine. However, when using a script to have the camera follow the object it runs into issues.

If I don't constrain the Y axis then I will get bouncing and as far as the x and z axis I get kind of a Flat Tire effect. Basically the camera doesn't follow smoothly it bounces around, stop go etc...

I have tried making the collider larger then the sphere and even using the position of the collider vs the object itself. I have also tried putting the code in Update / FixedUpdate / LateUpdate. What is the proper way to fix or address something like this? Here is my scripts below:

Camera Controller:

```
public class CamController : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject player;
private Vector3 offset;

void Start ()
{
    // Get the distance between the player ball and camera.
    offset = this.transform.position - player.transform.position;
}  

void LateUpdate ()
{       
    this.transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
}
}
```

Player Controller:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public float _speed;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Get input from keyboard.
    float _hoz = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float _ver = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    // Create a vector3 based on input from keyboard.
    Vector3 _move = new Vector3(_hoz, 0.0f, _ver);

    // Apply force to the voxel ball
    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(_move * _speed);
}
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SmoothFollow Script of Unity it self for getting smooth follow of camera.

Here are the steps how you can get the script:
1) Assets->Import Package->Scripts.
2) At the dialog that appears select all the scripts, or just the smooth follow one and hit Import button.
3) Now this script is in your project, and you can attach it to the camera.

Hope this will help you...

Best,
 Hardik.